# Call component function from another component — getting "Cannot read property" error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, components

I'm trying to call another component function from a component by Passing the reference of one component to another but getting  "Cannot read property" error. Here is the code

**Alert Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';    

@Component({
  selector: 'app-alert',
  templateUrl: './alert.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./alert.component.css']      
})

export class AlertComponent implements OnInit {  
  AlertMessage:string;

  constructor() {        
   }

  showSuccessAlert(){       
      this.AlertMessage =  "Data saved successfully.";
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**Alert component html**

```
<p>{{AlertMessage}}</p>
```

I'm calling `showSuccessAlert` function from another component

**Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { QueueService } from 'src/services/queue.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Queue } from 'src/models/queue';
import { error } from 'util';
import { AlertComponent } from '../alert/alert.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'queue-edit',
  templateUrl: './queue.edit.component.html'  
})
export class QueueEditComponent implements OnInit{
    @Input() alert:AlertComponent;

    queue = new Queue();    
    constructor(private api: QueueService, private route: ActivatedRoute){
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => this.params = params);

    } 
    title = "Edit Support Queue";

    ngOnInit() { 
    }

    @HostListener('saveQueue')
    saveQueue(queue){
        this.alert.showSuccessAlert(); 
    }
}
```

**html**

```
<app-alert></app-alert>
```

**ERROR**

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'showSuccessAlert' of undefined
    at QueueEditComponent.push../src/app/queue/queue.edit.component.ts.QueueEditComponent.saveQueue (queue.edit.component.ts:44)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (QueueEditComponent.html:25)
    at handleEvent (core.js:19545)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:20639)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:20342)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:16994)
    at core.js:17441
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:993)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:14051)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `@ViewChild` instead of `@Input`. Something like this:

```
import { ..., ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
...
import { AlertComponent } from '../alert/alert.component';

@Component({...})
export class QueueEditComponent implements OnInit{
    @ViewChild(AlertComponent) alert:AlertComponent;

    ...

    @HostListener('saveQueue')
    saveQueue(queue){
        this.alert.showSuccessAlert(); 
    }
}
```

---

**PS:** You won't have access to the `AlertComponent` in the `QueueEditComponent` until `ngAfterViewInit` is called. So make sure that your `saveQueue` get called sometime after `ngAfterViewInit`.